# FlatStyle Property not Displaying as Expected in Debug Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, .net-6.0

I placed controls like ComboBox and Button with the FlatStyle property in the design screen. Although I set them as FlatStyle.Standard or FlatStyle.Flat in the design screen and they appear that way during design time, when I debug the program, they appear in a 3D style.
The .NET version I'm using: .NET 6.

Btw, when I create a new .NET 6 Windows Forms application, there is no issue.

Design:
[image: Design]

Debug:
[image: Debug]

designer code:

```cs
comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox1.Location = new Point(273, 108);
comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
comboBox1.Size = new Size(155, 23); 
comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Thank you for all your help and contributions to the community.

Comment: Can you add the designer code?

Comment: `comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
comboBox1.Location = new Point(273, 108);
comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
comboBox1.Size = new Size(155, 23);
comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;`

Comment: Have you removed `Application.EnableVisualStyles()`?

Comment: you never seem to be setting the `comboBox1.FlatStyle` property according to that code snippet?

Comment: I didn't delete it, and the code doesn't come by default, but when I added it, it worked. Thank you so much! @Jimi

Comment: It is set by default, by the `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` method in `Program.cs` (or explicitly, if you have ported an older project). Unless you have not used the default Template, you have built a class library or a Console app